# Excel equal sign as first character in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get an equal sign "=" as first character in a cell to let the cell do a calculation. For example, the A column is representing, when present,  the formula like '=12*12' so you can see what's behind the result in the B column. With this behavior I'm trying to let Excel act like a calculator inspired by programs like Speedcruch and Speq.
Unfortunately Excel is doing strange things when I try some code, it looks like the active cell is jumping to a sort of random cell.
Here is what I've got:
What is going wrong here?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B1000")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
    Is Nothing Then
        
        If Left(Range(Target.Address), 1) = "=" Then
            ' Do nothing
        Else
            Range(Target.Address) = "=" & Range(Target.Address)
            Range(Target.Address).Select
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Changed code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
'If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B1000")) Is Nothing Then
    
    ' Change the range required
    ' Ensure target is a number before doing anything

        'If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        ' Stop any runtime errors
            On Error Resume Next
        
            ' Turn off events so a change doesn’t start an endless loop
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Dim Value
            Value = Chr(61) & Range(Target.Address).Value
            'MsgBox "Value: " & Value 'Range(Target.Address).Value

            If Left(Range(Target.Address).Value, 1) <> Chr(61) Then
            MsgBox "Value: " & Value
            Range(Target.Address).Formula = Value
            End If
                                    
            ' Turn events on
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        
            ' Allow run time errors again
            On Error GoTo 0
        'End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`

Comment: If you're entering the formula (eg. "12 * 12") into column A, isn't that the column you should be monitoring?

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reaction, I've got a little further with this code: 'code' Turn off events so a change doesn’t start an endless loop
            Application.EnableEvents = False

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments - it never ends well.  You can update your question if you have content to add.   It might help to explain exactly what your process looks like - what are you adding and where, and what is the event handler intended to achieve?

Comment: Are you still having a problem?  If Yes, what exactly is it?

Comment: I can continue with it for a while Tim, thanks for asking, I will come back if I got further questions. Btw are you familiar with the key down/up events? I like to watch when the user hits a +, -, * or / sign to do a calculation with the cell above, the 'ans' option just like on a simple calculator. Found some code for it but it is pretty sensitive to got that running in Excel from my opinion.

Comment: VBA doesn't run when a cell is in edit mode, so handling key events when the user is typing into a cell is not possible.  You'd need to position a textbox over the cell and have them edit in that if you wanted to be able to respond to keystrokes

Answer (score 0):

This code places an equals sign ('`=`') in front of every entry in column B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B1000")) Is Nothing _
    And Left(Target.Value, 1) <> Chr(61) Then
        Target.NumberFormat = "@"
        Target = Chr(61) & Target.Value
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

To get Excel to not treat the equals sign as a formula indicator, you need to set the `NumberFormat` property to 'Text', which is done in this line:

```
    Target.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Thanks JMP, I didn't know that. However it's okay that Excel treat column B as a formula, that's exactly what I want: typing a calculation and let Excel be so smart to put the equal sign at the front, put the result in column B and the formula content in column A, unless when it's text instead of a formula.

Comment: It's works so far for a '+' and '*' calculation but a '/' and '-' didn't work. For the '/' calculation Excel is showing te result in the formula line and not the formula itself. The '-' calculation I don't understand so far, for example '12-2' became '44167'. Anyone an idea why it is that way?

Comment: Excel sees '12-2' as the date 2nd Dec 2020, and returns the number of days that have elapsed since Jan 1st 1900, which is 44167. Type `=DATEVALUE("02-12-2020")` into the formula bar to see this.

Comment: Thank JMP for the explanation, how can I capture the input to do a calculation with a '-' or '/' sign?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but have a look at the Formulas->Show Formula button (about 2/3 to the right). This shows all your formulas in the sheet. Excel uses a format to decide how data entry is interpreted, you can alter this for a cell by right-clicking it, and then click 'Format Cells...'. Pick 'Number' to do calculations. In VBA this is set using the `NumberFormat` property of a `Range` object.