# Excel as daily calculator

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a simple 'daily calculator' in Excel in the style of programs like Speedcrunch and Speq. See also [Excel equal sign as first character in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069882/excel-equal-sign-as-first-character-in-cell)

It's just simple code and got the most things working. In the C column you can enter numbers or calculations, the B column is showing the formula behind the result. You can build on the cell above's result by, for example, simply only typing +10,*10,^2 and so on. The B column is based on the 'FORMULATEXT' function looking at the C column, if the C column starts with '=' show the content, else stay empty.

I've got a few questions:

1. When I use an AutoSum in the B column like `=SUM(C10:C11)` the result will show an error like '#NAME?'
2. When use `=SIN(RADIANS(45))` I've had the same error while `=SIN(45*PI()/180)` is working normally
3. The B column is preassigned now in the document, I've tried to add it by code but the cell stays empty, see the code, I've commented the tryout

Note that the input cells in the C column are forced to text by `NumberFormat = "@"`, I could not find another solution to capture the input from the cells as 'normal' characters and avoid getting datums when using the '/' sign or not recognizing the '+' sign.

Anyone any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot with the examples described]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Force the input column cells to text to ensure the text value is there
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        'Target.NumberFormat = "0.#########; [Red]-0.#########; [Blue]0.; [Magenta]@"
        Target.NumberFormat = "@"
    End If
    
    ' Prevent 'formula' cells being changed
    If ActiveCell.Column = 2 And ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then ActiveCell.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Select
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
     
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Stop any runtime errors
        On Error Resume Next
          
        ' Turn off events so a change doesn’t start an endless loop
        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        
        ' Set numberformat
        Target.NumberFormat = "0.#########"
        'Target.NumberFormat = "0.#########; [Red]-0.#########; [Blue]0.; [Magenta]@"
                
        If Left(Target.Value, 2) = "--" Then ' Typ '--' to have a negative value
            Target.Formula = Replace(Target.Formula, "--", "-")
        ElseIf Left(Target.Value, 1) = "+" Or _
               Left(Target.Value, 1) = "-" Or _
               Left(Target.Value, 1) = "*" Or _
               Left(Target.Value, 1) = "/" Or _
               Left(Target.Value, 1) = "^" Then
                    
            Target.Formula = Chr(61) & Target.Offset(rowoffset:=-1, columnoffset:=0).Address & Target.Formula
                    
            ' Remove $ sign to make the formula non relative
            Target.Formula = Replace(Target.Formula, "$", "")
        ElseIf Left(Target.Value, 4) = "=SOM" Then
            Target.Formula = Target.Formula
        ElseIf Left(Target.Value, 1) = Chr(61) Then
            Target.Formula = Target.Formula
        ElseIf IsAlpha(Target.Value) Then
            Target.Formula = Target.Formula
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Target.Formula = Target.Formula
        ElseIf Left(Target.Value, 1) <> Chr(61) Then
            Target.Formula = Chr(61) & Target.Formula
        End If
                    
        ' Try to fill the cell in the B-column, who is preassigned now in the document
'        Dim Value As String
'        Value = "ALS(OF(ISGETAL(VIND.SPEC(""="";FORMULETEKST(" & Target.Address & ");1)));FORMULETEKST(" & Target.Address & ");"""")"
'        Value = Replace(Value, "$", "")
'        MsgBox Value
'        Target.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=2).Formula = Chr(61) & Value
                                
        ' Reset numberformat to text
        Target.NumberFormat = "@"
                 
        ' Turn events on
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        ' Allow run time errors again
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub

Function IsAlpha(s) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = Len(s) And Not s Like "*[!a-z A-Z]*"
End Function
```

Comment: Unless you have an error or problem, your question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Any suggestions? Just use Speedcrunch or Speq. Why bother trying to waste the effort to adapt a powerful computing tool to everyday calculations? Especially if you already know that a ready-made tool exists!

Comment: I see that errors are only occuring with functions that are different in a dutch vs. an english excel.    It must have something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

You've rather over complecated things.

1. Don't use a general On Error Resume Next - it just hides errors.  If some of you code *might* error, you can use OERN tightly bound around that code, closely followed `On Error GoTo ?` and handle the specific error case
2. the `.Formula`  property expects US_EN format formula.  You can either use `.FormulaLocal` and use your local language, of rewrite in US_EN
3. All those `ElseIf`'s do nothing.  Delete them.
4. There is no need foir the formatting at all
5. You formula for Column `B` could be simply eg `=IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(C2)` (in US_EN, I'll leave it to you to translate)
6. Note, your SelectionChange event doesn't stop someone pasting a range of values over column B
   Your code, refactoed

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Prevent 'formula' cells being changed
    ' Also handle multiple cell selection that includes column B
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim FormulaString As String

    ' Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
    ' also exit if changed cell is in row 1
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Turn off events so a change doesn’t start an endless loop
        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        
        If Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 2) = "--" Then ' Typ '--' to have a negative value
            Target.FormulaLocal = Replace(Target.FormulaLocal, "--", "-")
        ElseIf Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 1) = "+" Or _
               Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 1) = "-" Or _
               Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 1) = "*" Or _
               Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 1) = "/" Or _
               Left$(Target.FormulaLocal, 1) = "^" Then
                    
            Target.FormulaLocal = "=" & Target.Offset(rowoffset:=-1, columnoffset:=0).Address & Target.FormulaLocal
                    
            ' Remove $ sign to make the formula non relative
            Target.FormulaLocal = Replace(Target.FormulaLocal, "$", vbNullString)
        End If
                    
        ' Fill the cell in the B-column
        ' Or use my alternative formula
        FormulaString = "=ALS(OF(ISGETAL(VIND.SPEC(""="";FORMULETEKST(" & Target.Address & ");1)));FORMULETEKST(" & Target.Address & ");"""")"
        Target.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1).FormulaLocal = FormulaString
                                
    End If
EH:
    ' Turn events on
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer, very educational for me.